# What are the capitalisation rules for prefixes in parentheses?

Tags: capitalization, prefixes, parentheses

If you'd like to write (co)promotor at the beginning of a sentence, should both 'co' and 'promotor' be capitalised? For example, is it "(Co)Promotors are advised to ..."? Or is there another standard way of writing this?

Comment: **Do not write answers in comments.** If you have answer, write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is to capitalize the first letter of a sentence, and most references do not make exceptions for parentheses. For example:

> Always capitalize the first word of a sentence. ([Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-rules/))
> You should always capitalize the first letter of the first word in a sentence, no matter what the word is. ([thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/when-to-capitalize-words/))
> Capitalize the first word of every sentence. (The Gregg Reference Manual, 10th ed., section 301)

(Interestingly enough, my version of CMOS does not seem to mention capitalization at the beginning of a sentence at all.)

There is no reason to capitalize the "p" in your first word. Therefore:

> (Co)promoters<sup>1</sup> are advised to . . .

To avoid this issue entirely, you could reword the sentence:

> Promoters and copromoters are advised to . . .

or, assuming that "copromoters" constitute a subset of promoters, simply:

> Promoters are advised to . . .

---

<sup>1</sup>"Promotor" seems to be a relatively rare word, so I'm using "promoter" instead. The principle is, of course, the same.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Comment: A promotor rather than an amateur motor...

Comment: @GEdgar always appreciate a wordplay :')